# How to define onClick handler method in XML for dialog buttons using FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialog

I'm trying to define an onClick handler method in an XML layout for buttons in a **Dialog** but the app crashes when the buttons are clicked due to NoSuchMethodException (it can't find the method). The method signature is `public void searchMovies(View)` and I can **guarantee** that it is spelled consistently in the XML file and in code. This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243704/using-onclick-attribute-in-layout-xml-causes-a-nosuchmethodexception-in-android/4321080#4321080) provides a solution by putting the putting the method into the **Activity** that the Dialog belongs to, but that doesn't work for me.

However, I'm using a **FragmentActivity** and FragmentStatePagerAdapter, so maybe this is the reason it doesn't work for me? I've tried putting the method into the FragmentActivity, the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the Fragment and also the anonymous OnClickListener class that handles launching the Dialog. None of them have worked, all give NoSuchMethodException error. Again, I can *guarantee* that the method is spelled correctly/consistently.

I know that I can do this programmatically, but it would be much more convenient if I could do it the other way. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: If I have not misunderstood you, the best way to achieve it, in my opinion, is to subclass `Dialog/DialogFragment` and add the method your subclass. I am assuming the the layout with the onClick property is the custom view for your dialog.

Comment: "I am assuming the layout..." => yes, that's right. I'll give what you're suggesting a go.

Comment: Adding the method to my new Dialog subclass did not work. However, adding the method to the FragmentActivity, as well as using the Dialog subclass is working. This is actually the whole solution set out in the other question referenced in my question. I just wasn't implementing it properly. Anyway, that's the way to go. Thanks for the help @blackbelt

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments above, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243704/using-onclick-attribute-in-layout-xml-causes-a-nosuchmethodexception-in-android/4321080#4321080) is the solution (I suppose this is a duplicate, then, but I reckon it still might be useful to someone looking for the solution. I don't mind if someone feels that it should be deleted though).