# onClick not work on Custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, onclick

I'm customming dialog (extend `Dialog`) with a custom layout:

```
setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_call, null));
```

in this layout, I have some TextView and Button need catch button click event so that I put `android:onClick="onClick"` to each view.

In `.java` file I implemented `public void onClick(View v){....}`

However when I click each view, I received crash and It show that it not found `onClick`.

I also tried add `android:clickable="true"` to each view in XML file but not success.

What is my wrong here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243704/using-onclick-attribute-in-layout-xml-causes-a-nosuchmethodexception-in-android please refer this answer

Comment: it is difficult if I must defined a onClick method with each activity that I use my Dialog.

Comment: Instead of directly using android:onClick="onClick" method, why dont you implement the OnClickListener and override the onClick(View view) method in the dialog class.

Answer (score 2):

```
 AlertDialog dialog;
    View v=// dialog layout ;
    dialog.setContentView(v);
    Button btn = v.findViewById(your Button id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your code 
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes, I know this solution will work fine. But because I have many view in XML need implement onClick method, so that I choice add Click event by android:onClick.

Comment: inflate(R.layout.dialog_call) it is not root layout that;s way onclick not work

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.